# Angular router.es5.js - Cannot read property 'path' of undefined, Cannot read property 'canonicalUrl' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, path, breeze, grammar, router

I used the breeze TempHire sample project (found here: http://breeze.github.io/doc-samples/temp-hire-angular.html ) as a starting point for my project. Upon booting this sample project, i already get a path error in the console (at serializeInstruction ), but the app seemed to run fine so i went with it.
Quite some time later, i got to the point where i needed a link with parameters (/:id), and i cannot for the life of me get the router to do it. 
Tried with ng-link and the breeze apps method

```
<a href="/#/contacts/{{contact.id}}">{{contact.name}}</a>
```

along with some other attempts, all in vain. 
I have tried multiple versions of the router, all the workarounds people found but nothing seems to work. I keep getting the following errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'canonicalUrl' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'canonicalUrl' of undefined
>       at Grammar.recognize

and while routing on the navbar

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
>       at serializeInstruction

To clarify, it appears that only the Grammar.recognize error actually blocks the routing.

Here is the code that causes that error:
Initial router config in my shell.js:

```
self.navigations = [
            { href: '/#/home', title: 'Home' },
            { href: '/#/contacts', title: 'Contact Management' }
        ];

        self.$router.config([
           { path: '/home', component: 'home' },
           { path: '/contacts', component: 'contacts' },
        ]);
        self.$location.path('/home');
```

In contacs.js:

```
function controller($q, $router, errorhandler, unitofwork, $modal, logger) {
    $router.config([
        {
            path: '/:id',
            component : 'tags'
        }
    ]);
```

In contacts.html:

```
<tr class="selectable-row" ng-repeat="contact in contacts.contacts track by $index">
            <td><a href="/#/contacts/{{contact.id}}">{{contact.name}}</a></td>
```

Note: contacts in my project are not related to contacts in the sample app.

Please let me know if more code or clarification is needed.

If somebody has an idea about solving this, i would greatly appreciate your input.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the value of the `contact` object (maybe consoling contacts.contacts could help)? How is this object instantiated (AJAX)? Use `ng-href` instead of plain `href` when the value is set by angular dynamically.

Comment: Hello Lucio, thank you for your reply.
Contact is an entity created on the server with EF Code first. I am sure the problem is not with that object as i am displaying all it's properties in the table on the same view via ng-repeat. It is fetched with breeze (which i believe uses ajax). Neither ng-href or href worked for me.

Comment: So, what the value of the object is?

Comment: The TempHire app uses the [New Router](https://angular.github.io/router/), which is still alpha, so expect some bugs and breaking changes.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to remove the newRouter and replace it with the older ui-router which works. Honestly don't know why breeze would put something so unstable in a sample application.